# How to trigger getting next element of an array after a certain value is met in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am somewhat new in Javascript.
I have a script where I need to access 2 arrays.

```
const days = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13",
    "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"
]; //Array [A]

const months = ["01", "02", "03", "04"]; //Array[B]
```

These 2 arrays are being used in parallel. They are both inside a looping/iterating function.

FOR ARRAY[A] --- As for each iteration...values of this array will be extracted one by one and will restart (back to the first index) once all the values is finished.

FOR ARRAY [B] --- In parallel with Array[A], this array will only extract the first index value upon each iteration and will ONLY get the next index value if the value of Array[A] becomes 28. The Array[B] should also repeat (start again from first index value) if it has reach its end.

```
export default function() { //this is an iterating function.
   var i;
   var z = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {

    var objectInResponse = days[i]; //get current object
    var objectInResponse2 = months[z];
    console.log("Day Value: ", objectInResponse, " Month Value: ", objectInResponse2);

    if (objectInResponse == 28) {
        z = z + 1;

    }

}
  // the extracted values of Array A and Array B will be used at some 
  // code here (outside the for loop) **/
}
```

What is the better approach for this? Any suggestions?

**Edit:** For a more better logic illustration. It's more of like a Month-Date relationship. Note that months are in a form of numbers in the given example array and the dates are up to 28 only and not 31. After reaching 28, proceed to next month.

**Example:**

Iteration 1 = January 1

Iteration 2 = January 2
....

Iteration 28 = January 28

Iteration 29 = February 1

Iteration 30 = February 2

Comment: Can you share the code? It's easier for us to help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+iterate+two+arrays+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Are you building a grid of number/letter pairs?

Comment: Hi @CharlesBamford, not a grid of pairs. I just need to trigger Array[B] to access its next index value if Array[A] becomes 28

Comment: @RuiCosta I modified the post for some sample code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is made overly complex by tracking the days in an array, where the value is the index + 1. It would be easier just to count the number of times the function has been called and add 1 to it, but to do that, you'd need your function to be able to remember things.

Javascript has a bunch of solutions for this problem. The three biggest (AFAIK) are IIFEs, generators and classes.

For one offs like this, I tend to prefer Immediately Invoked Function Expressions. I find them easier to set up and more intuitive to use than classes or generators.

The following example has the logic for the problem all annotated. The next two examples don't have annotations, because they would just say the same thing.

```js
// IIFE
const incrementDay = (() => {
  // Set up iteration. This tracks the number of times the function is called.
  // It starts at -1 because I increment it first. I could increment it last,
  // and start it at zero, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.
  let iteration = -1;
  
  // Since the days are just a bunch of numbers, they don't need to be set into
  // an array. We only need to know how many there are.
  const maxDays = 28;
  
  // Yeah, months.
  const months = ["a", "b","c"];
  
  // This is the function that actually is saved in incrementDay.
  return () => {
    // Increment iteration.
    iteration++;
    
    // The day is the remainder of iteration divided by the number of days. +1
    // because months usually don't have a day zero. I blame the Romans.
    const day = iteration % maxDays + 1;
    
    // The month is the iterations divided by the number of days in a month.
    // Modding (%) makes the result cyclical, same as the days.
    const month = months[Math.floor(iteration / maxDays) % months.length]
    
    // The result of the current iteration.
    return [month, day]
  }
})();

// Just demo stuff. nbd.
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", () => console.log(incrementDay()));
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click me"></input>
```

Here's the same code as a generator. It's basically the same logically as the iife above, but it's a slightly different syntax. You can find in depth docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

```js
function * dayGenerator() {
  let iteration = -1;
  const maxDays = 28;
  const months = ["a", "b","c"];
  
  while (true) {
    iteration++;
    
    const day = iteration % maxDays + 1;
    
    const month = months[Math.floor(iteration / maxDays) % months.length]
    
    yield([month, day]);
  }
};

const day = dayGenerator();

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", () => console.log(day.next().value));
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Generate!"></input>
```

For the sake of completion, here's the same thing again, but as an es6 class.

```js
class DayIncrementer {
  constructor() {
    this.iteration = -1;
    this.maxDays = 28;
    this.months = ["a", "b","c"];
  }
  
  next = () => {
    this.iteration++;
    
    const day = this.iteration % this.maxDays + 1;
    
    const month = this.months[Math.floor(this.iteration / this.maxDays) % this.months.length];
    return [month, day];
  }
}

const day = new DayIncrementer();

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", () => console.log(day.next()));
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Classy"></input>
```

Incidentally, any one of these could trigger an integer overflow if you were building a calendar for the next 45035996273704 years or so. I didn't think it would be an issue, and to keep the code as simple as possible, I didn't reset the iteration variable, but you could check every time the day is 1 and the month is "a", reset the iteration variable.

Comment: Wow. Thank you thank you so much for these very useful information. I am still finding my way here in Javascript and you just made me challenge myself to put extra effort in learning more. Lol. Will try these solutions. Thank you!

Comment: May I know what would be the approach then if we set maxDays=28 into an array form (1-28). The days are in an array form also same as to months?

Comment: You put the days into the array, then do `const day = daysArray[iteration % daysArray.length]` instead of `iteration % maxDays + 1`. You'd also need to replace maxDays in the month calculation with daysArray.length.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let i = 1;

const days = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13",
  "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"
]; //Array [A]

const months = ["01", "02", "03", "04"]; //Array[B]

months.forEach(month => {

  days.forEach(day => {

    console.log(`Interaction ${i} = ${month} ${day}`)

      ++i
  })


});
```